# How do you make code which only gets compiled for platforms which can perform unaligned reads?

Tags: optimization, rust, memory-alignment

The purpose of the function below is to speed-up (possibly unaligned) u64 reads from slices.

The optimised function compiles to `mov rax, qword ptr [rdi]` on x86_64 and `ldr x0, [x0]` on aarch64.  (The unoptimised version (when used on a little-endian platform) gets compiled to the same assembly, but often explodes into more than sixteen instructions when inlined at -O3.)

This code is not yet correct (see the FIXME):

```
// Unoptimised version, suitable for both endianesses and any lack of unaligned reads.
#[cfg(target_endian="big")]
fn u64_from_slice(slice: &[u8]) -> u64 {
    debug_assert!(slice.len() >= size_of::<u64>());
    unsafe {
        *slice.get_unchecked(0) as u64 | 
        ((*slice.get_unchecked(1) as u64) << 8) |
        ((*slice.get_unchecked(2) as u64) << 16) |
        ((*slice.get_unchecked(3) as u64) << 24) |
        ((*slice.get_unchecked(4) as u64) << 32) |
        ((*slice.get_unchecked(5) as u64) << 40) |
        ((*slice.get_unchecked(6) as u64) << 48) |
        ((*slice.get_unchecked(7) as u64) << 56)
    }
}

// FIXME: This is only valid on architectures which can perform unaligned reads.
#[cfg(target_endian="little")]
pub fn u64_from_slice(slice: &[u8]) -> u64 {
    debug_assert!(slice.len() >= size_of::<u64>());
    unsafe {
        let r = &*(slice as *const [u8] as *const [u8; size_of::<u64>()]);
        *mem::transmute::<&[u8; size_of::<u64>()], &u64>(r)
    }
}
```

Many years ago I worked on ARM architectures where unaligned reads caused an aligned read followed by a rearrangement of the bytes so that the u8 or u16 at that address was moved to the lowest bits of the register.

In this case, my `target_endian="little"` isn't sufficient to make the code above correct.

How do I make sure that those ARM architectures (and possibly others) are excluded from running the optimised version?

Comment: This code is **never** correct, it is always UB. Because you are not compiling for whatever platform, you are compiling for the Rust Abstract Machine, and it only supports unaligned loads via raw pointers (even creating a reference is UB) and `std::ptr::read_unaligned()`. Anything else is UB.

Comment: Besides, you can get rid of the unsafe code in `let r` by doing `let r = <&[u8; size_of::<u64>()]>::try_from(&slice[..size_of::<u64>()])`. You can then get rid of the assert too.

Comment: Another point, this code is unsound: you are using a `debug_assert!()` to verify unsafe precondition, you must use `assert!()` or make the function unsafe.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks for your comments.  It is important for me to prove that Rust can equal C in the generated assembly.  Further thinking has let me devise a way of achieving both speed and safety (in my answer below) by implementing two specialised versions with no unsafe code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The optimised function compiles to `mov rax, qword ptr [rdi]` on x86_64 and `ldr x0, [x0]` on aarch64.

Is it really such a useful gain when `from_le_bytes` is so very close, and an `unreachable_unchecked()` in the failure branch basically gets you there? The only thing both retain is a branch on the size of the slice, but that should be a ridiculously well predicted branch.

> Many years ago I worked on ARM architectures where unaligned reads caused an aligned read followed by a rearrangement of the bytes so that the u8 or u16 at that address was moved to the lowest bits of the register.

You might be thinking about ARMv6 and older, especially ARMv5 and down, which would round address down to a multiple of 4 then possibly do weird rotations.

AVMv8 supports unaligned reads just fine, at least for most operations, though there may be a perf hit.

> How do I make sure that those ARM architectures (and possibly others) are excluded from running the optimised version?

I think explicitly enumerating with [`target_arch`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#target_arch) is your least bad bet, it'll probably leave perfs on the table as handling of unaligned read is not always an ISA property (especially when it comes to performance profile).

Answer (score 1):

While not resolving the original question, I was able to satisfy my requirements with no unsafe code, by not using slices at all:

```
#![feature(slice_as_chunks)]
...
pub fn u64_from_first_eight(buf: &[u8; 9]) -> u64 {
    let parts: (&[[u8; 8]], &[u8]) = buf.as_chunks();
    u64::from_le_bytes(parts.0[0])
}

pub fn u64_from_last_eight(buf: &[u8; 9]) -> u64 {
    let parts: (&[u8], &[[u8; 8]]) = buf.as_rchunks();
    u64::from_le_bytes(parts.1[0])
}
```

These generate efficient assembly code.

x86_64:

```
example::u64_from_first_eight:
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        ret

example::u64_from_last_eight:
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi + 1]
        ret
```

aarch64:

```
example::u64_from_first_eight:
        ldr     x0, [x0]
        ret

example::u64_from_last_eight:
        ldur    x0, [x0, #1]
        ret
```

---

Update: Thanks to Chayim Friedman, I now have the following code which does not depend on nightly features, and yet compiles to the same single assembly instructions.

```
pub fn u64_from_low_eight(buf: &[u8; 9]) -> u64 {
    let bytes: &[u8; size_of::<u64>()] = buf[..size_of::<u64>()].try_into().unwrap();
    u64::from_le_bytes(*bytes)
}

pub fn u64_from_high_eight(buf: &[u8; 9]) -> u64 {
    let bytes: &[u8; size_of::<u64>()] = buf[1..(size_of::<u64>()+1)].try_into().unwrap();
    u64::from_le_bytes(*bytes)
}
```

Comment: You can avoid nightly features with `let v: &[u8; size_of::<u64>()] = buf[..size_of::<u64>()].try_into().unwrap();`. The check will be optimized away.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks, I can confirm that the check is optimised away - I really hadn't expected the compiler to be so clever.